# mysqldump: you need PROCESS privileges for this operation

Tags: linux, ssh, командная-строка

Пытаюсь выполнить команду `mysqldump` из-под root-пользователя - уже не в первый раз, ранее выполнял, и все было нормально. Сейчас выдает такую ошибку:

> mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the
> PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump
> tablespaces

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: При указании параметров пользователя БД и его пароль `mysqldump -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS` ошибка сохраняется?

Comment: @PotroNik, да указываю с именем и паролем. Притом, команда у меня сохранена, использую без изменений - раньше работало, а теперь не хочет. Настройки сервера не менялись, место на диске есть.

Comment: А пользователь в БД не изменился? Может быть кто-то поменял пароль именно на пользователя БД

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить флаг --no-tablespaces

Ссылка на документацию [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-tablespaces)